# iPhone 3G S sync services problem

Tags: windows, iphone, itunes, sync

When I try and synchronise my iPhone with iTunes, I get a dialog informing me that "syncing has been disabled on this computer". (I've never disabled syncing myself, and it worked perfectly fine a day ago) Music synchronises fine, as do videos, however, my contacts do not. Google Contacts no longer appears in the list to choose from, and the select box is empty.

When I choose to re-enable syncing, iTunes informs me that "iTunes was unable to load provider data from Sync Services". I've followed several steps I've found on the internet, including deleting the `C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\Sync Services` directory, but to no avail.

Any ideas on what could be causing this? Is there a Service (in the Windows-form-of-daemon sense) that I accidentally disabled?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error once I contact my Iphone 3GS to Itunes 911. I have done many times, reinstalling itunes, etc.
Finanlly I solved it per accident: when I have no internet connection, everythings go smoothly. it seems that my itunes wants to get some info from apple or so. in offline mode, I am now able to back up and sync my apps rapidly.
hope it helps you also
Regards, Armand